# Weighted Random in Golang

Tags: go

I have to do weighted Random in Golang but I'm getting an error:

```
multiple-value randutil.WeightedChoice() in single-value context
```

Code:

```
package main

import "fmt"
import "github.com/jmcvetta/randutil"

func main() {    
    choices := make([]randutil.Choice, 0, 2)    
    choices = append(choices, randutil.Choice{1, "dg"})
    choices = append(choices, randutil.Choice{2, "n"})    
    result := randutil.WeightedChoice(choices)    
    fmt.Println(choices)
}
```

Any help will be deeply appreciated.

Answer (score 7):

The `func WeightedChoice(choices []Choice) (Choice, error)`
returns `Choice, error`, so use `result, err := randutil.WeightedChoice(choices)`, like this working code:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"

    "github.com/jmcvetta/randutil"
)

func main() {
    choices := make([]randutil.Choice, 0, 2)
    choices = append(choices, randutil.Choice{1, "dg"})
    choices = append(choices, randutil.Choice{2, "n"})
    fmt.Println(choices) // [{1 dg} {2 n}]

    result, err := randutil.WeightedChoice(choices)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    fmt.Println(result) //{2 n}
}
```

output:

```
[{1 dg} {2 n}]
{2 n}
```

Answer (score 0):

`WeightedChoice` returns an error you aren't acknowledging in your code.

Comment: @digiadit the important thing to remember is you have to acknowledge all returned variables, if you want to not use a variable, you can use a `_` in place of the variable name. Typically, it's important to never avoid errors.